# how to use vim to open every .txt file under a directory (with Bash)

Tags: bash, vim, while-loop

I am trying the following to use a `vim` to open every `txt` file under current directory.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print | while read aline; do
  read -p "start spellchecking fine: $aline" sth
  vim $aline
done
```

Running it in `bash` complains with

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: Finished.
```

Can anyone explain what could possibly goes wrong? Also, I intend to use `read -p` for prompt before using vim, without no success.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
vim $( find . -name "*.txt" )
```

To fix your solution, you can (probably) do:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print | while read aline; do
      read -p "start spellchecking fine: $aline" sth < /dev/tty
      vim $aline < /dev/tty
done
```

The problem is that the entire while loop is taking its input from find, and vim inherits that pipe as its stdin.  This is one technique for getting vim's input to come from your terminal.  (Not all systems support `/dev/tty`, though.)

Comment: is it possible if I want to prompt with "read -p" before opening a vim?

Answer (score 1):

With `shopt -s globstar` you can purge out find and thus make bash not execute vim in a subshell that receives output from find:

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s failglob
for file in **/*.txt ; do
    read -p "Start spellchecking fine: $file" sth
    vim "$file"
done
```

. Another idea is using

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.txt") ; do
```

(in case there are no filenames with spaces or newlines.)

Comment: `endfor` is funny but incorrect... replace it with `done`. Also, you should quote `"$file"`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thanks. When working in zsh you don’t need to care, so I forgot about quoting.

Comment: Maybe you should also `shopt -s nullglob` just in case there are no files matching `**/*.txt`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf It is applicable in this case, but zsh behavior is IMHO better: glob expanded to nothing results in an error and stopped execution: `failglob` option. `nullglob` is needed only in a limited set of safe cases.

Comment: With `nullglob` it just doesn't do anything (as it would be the case with `find` the OP used). `failglob` is probably better, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

Often the simplest solution is the best, and I believe this is it:

```
vim -o `find . -name \*.txt -type f`
```

The -type f is to ensure only files ending .txt are opened as you don't discount the possibility that there may be subdirectories that have names that end in ".txt".

This will open each file in a seperate window/bufer in vim, if you don't require this and are happy with using :next and :prefix to navigate through the files, remove "-o" from the suggested comand-line above.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to open all files in one single `vim` instance is (provided the number of files doesn't exceed the maximal number of arguments):

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec vim {} +
```

Another possibility that fully answers the OP, but with the benefit that it is safe regarding file names containing spaces or funny symbols.

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec bash -c 'read -p "start spellchecking $0"; vim "$0"' {} \;
```

Comment: Raging downvoters, please leave a note to explain why you think this is not useful or wrong. It might be better to do so, so that I can either fix the answer or delete it!